# Tweetinvi - The name 'auth' does not exist in the current context

Tags: twitter, tweetinvi

I watched a video on Youtube. I uploaded Tweetinvi. I wrote the same code in the video, but there was an error. I don't know what i did wrong. Error: The name 'Auth' does not exist in the current context

```
 using Tweetinvi;

namespace test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Auth.SetCredentials("", "", "", "");
        }
        private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Auth for older versions. Check Tweetinvi 5.0.3 documentation out https://linvi.github.io/tweetinvi/dist/twitter-api-v1.1/tweets.html